# Excel converting data entered to 10% of correct value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having a problem with all of my ExcelWorksheets. Any number that I  Type into a cell is converted to 10% of the value I typed. For instance, if I type in 100 into a cell, the data displayed is 10. It does this for all of the cells in the worksheet and if I create a new worksheet, the problem persists.

I have looked for hidden macros and cannot find any macros, nor is there a formula showing in the cells to convert the typed value to 10% of its value.

This is really become a big problem for me as I'm working on a multimillion dollar budget and can't  work around this  problem by putting in values that are 10 times the value I want to see because other people looking at the spreadsheet on their machines will see the correct value.

This problem started after I used Time Machine to transfer my files from an old iMac to my new iMac. I am using 10.10.5 with office 2011 and Excel version 14.5.3, which I believe is the most recent version.

Our IT guys have not even wanted to look at this problem and I am desperate for a solution.

Comment: If you type I a decimal number like say `10.33` what does it display? Have you tried reinstalling Office?

Comment: What happens when setting the cell alignment to Center?

Comment: If you enter values and do calculations; do you get 1/10 as result also? => CTRL+1 - custom display format set to some peculiar thing?

Comment: You've checked the formatting of the cells to make sure it's normal?  This can be used to scale up and down, but a factor of 10 is hard to achieve so I don't really think this is the case.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, and isn't answerable without additional information and clarification from the OP.  Voting to close as unclear.